# Android in-app purchase v3 fails only with signed build on 2.3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

We use the new Google IAB v3 API, it has been very reliable but one case fails: it does not work with a signed build running on 2.3.4 (a Droid X).

Symptom is `IInAppBillingService.isBillingSupported()` returns 3 which means `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE`.

I'm stumped because all these cases work:
- 2.3.4 with debug build: OK
- 4.2.1 with debug OR signed build, with/without proguard: OK

Even though it worked with proguard on 4.2 I wondered if it was an obfuscation problem, so tried keep class `com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService`, then completely turned off proguard. No change.

So it seems to be something about the signed release and only on 2.3. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the Google Play store is on the device? See: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html

Comment: Build Version 3.10.10. My 4.2 Nexus 7 that doesn't have the problem is also 3.10.10

Comment: That's the app build version; I can't query the in-app billing API version directly. But I don't think it is as simple as the wrong version of Google Play store because why would that work with debug build but not with signed?

Comment: I've implemented this recently, and there was a bug where I had to clear the Play Store cache, then re-run it and accept the terms to get the payments to work.  Pretty miserable from a user's perspective, but I haven't found a workaround. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks Michael, clearing just the cache did not work, you have to force quit and then clear both cache and data for Google Play. Then you'll get the T&C accept when you launch it. After then when I tried IAB from our app I got the IAB T&C accept and it all works. I have no idea why this only happens with the signed build, but very glad it is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload an apk to the Google Play Developer Console? You need to do this when you want to first start testing IAB, and every time you bump your version code.